# Anybody know how to make a search in a app that searches the database?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, search

I am working on an app in swift and need help. I am trying to have a search object on the screen and when you type letters it will bring a result from the realtime database using firebase. Please help. I don't know how I can code that. Please Please Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be a bit more specific about what exactly is it that you are trying to do. Firstly - what technologies are you using? JavaScript? What framewroks? React? Angular? Vuejs? Vanilla JavaScript? Is it a restful application you are doing or server rendered?

Depending on your answers to the above questions the code can vary greatly. Here I can give you a general solution though:

- first create the search box and a button with an action that sends a request (mostly HTML)
- that request can be an AJAX GET request to look for results in the database, based on a certain search keyword. I recommend a library called axios to help you with that. (sending and resolving promises with JavaScript)
- handle the response of that request and if the response is valid (with status 200) then update your search results. (mostly JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

I just did this a few weeks ago for my app you are in luck! I am using swift programming language btw.

So according to firebase you should not use firebase to search for documents in the database. [Firebase Documentation on this.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search). Instead you should use something else like "Algolia", "Elastic", or "typeSense". I chose to use Algolia and it took me about a day to implementing my app. Super easy.

But if you really want to use firebase (which is not recommended) you could use this:

```
    func loadPost(lastDoc: QueryDocumentSnapshot?, completion: @escaping (QueryDocumentSnapshot?) -> Void) {
    let db: Query
    // Check to see if previous documents have been loaded or not.
    if let lastDoc = lastDoc {
        db = Firestore.firestore().collection("collection name")
            .order(by: "document name you are wanting to get. example: postTitle, username, date, etc")
            // Amount of documents you want to retrieve from your colleciton
            .limit(to: 10)
            // Check certain conditions that you want to retrieve.
            // In this example we are only retrieving the posts that have 100 reports or greater.
            .whereField("reportCount", isGreaterThan: 100)
            // Start after the previous loaded document so we don't waste data by reloading documents that have already been loaded.
            .start(afterDocument: lastDoc)
        
        // If there are no previous loaded documents then you just start from the beginning of your collection colleciton.
    } else {
        db = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
            .order(by: "document name", descending: true)
            .limit(to: 10)
            .whereField("document name", isGreaterThan: 100)
    }
    // finally get the documents you want from firebase
    db.getDocuments { query, error in
        
        // Check for errors
        if let query = query, error == nil {
            
            // Not really sure why you need a dispatchgroup, but its kind of like a completionHandler for a for loop.
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            for doc in query.documents {
                group.enter()
                // run the code you need to run:
                
                
                // After the code is finished running you need to call group.leave()
                group.leave()
                }
            // After the for loop is completely done call group.notify which is basically like a completionHandler
            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                // notify whatever needs to be notified.
                
                // finally insert the last document loaded so when we need to load data again it only loads documents that have not been loaded.
                completion(query.documents.last)
            }
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How would I put this with the search bar? BTW this is that database I am using (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pSaHbBT4NpNUszpF7eQSO6b6A9TgKvL-/view?usp=sharing) I am using realtime database not firestore. Thanks

Comment: @user14963385  Sorry I didn't see you were using realtime database, but I have never used realtime database so I have no idea. If I were you I would use Algolia.